# How can my sprite body will jump and come back to original place in box2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

How can my sprite will jump and come back to original place??
I am using box2d physics engine in iphone apps.
I am using impulse but cant work properly.

Is any one know the logic or code than tell me.

```
-(void)jump
{
    b2Vec2 pos=ballbody->GetPosition();
 //   float vel=ballbody->GetAngularVelocity();
    double radian=atan2(pos.x+10, pos.y+10);
    float angle=CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radian);
    NSLog(@"Angle: %f",angle);
     float impulseFactor = 1.0;
   float force=ballbody->GetMass()*10;
    //force/=6.0;
    //b2Vec2 force=b2Vec2(0,50.0f);
  //  float apply=force*JUMP_IMPULSE*impulseFactor;
    ballbody->ApplyLinearImpulse(b2Vec2(angle,force), ballbody->GetWorldCenter());

 //  [self applyLinearImpulse:b2Vec2(0,[self mass]*JUMP_IMPULSE*impulseFactor) point:[self worldCenter]];

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have already.. and what exactly "isn't working" about returning to the original position

Comment: sprite body jump when i apply force but cant come to jump position.

Comment: You mean it doesn't come back down?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to jump sprite an any angle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470490/how-to-jump-sprite-an-any-angle)

Comment: The tick/update method used in the HelloWorldLayer initially keeps moving down the sprites towards down. Have you checked that one?

Answer (score 0):

1. please check whether gravity has been set
2. if not set gravity upon the particular angle you have put the force.
3. third case is note down that position... get the current position... get angle.... set linear velocity to that angle.... keep on checking the position and as soon as it reaches that position set linear velocity zero..... (this sounds confusing but i didn't understood your problem fully so as much as i did understood i can help only this much)